# How can tcp socket client in python talk with uwsgi?

Tags: python, sockets, nginx, uwsgi, python-sockets

How can ***tcp socket client*** in python talk with uwsgi ?

my architectures are

tcp socket client -> nginx -> uwsgi

tcp socket client -> uwsgi

Answer (score 1):

By talking the `uwsgi` protocol to a socket. The protocol is described [here in the uWSGI documentation](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Protocol.html).

The Python docs contain [a decent tutorial regarding TCP and Unix sockets here](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/sockets.html).

**EDIT:** See https://github.com/akx/uwsgi-socket-example for a working example.

Comment: here is the my demo 
@AKX https://gist.github.com/ogta/aae2bcfda27834b4a9166cfb23f07a41 but not working

Comment: What do you expect sending a random string to an uWSGI socket to do?

Comment: @ogta I've added a link to a working example to the post.